On Minbar, who decides what the public needs to know?
In the beginning of the episode Divided Loyalties, Sheridan and Delenn are discussing the news media on Earth (apparently JMS thought newspapers would still be a thing in the mid-2200's). Delenn says that on her homeworld the public is told "only what they need to know".
What she doesn't say is (and I'm a little surprised Sheridan doesn't ask this) who determines what the people need to know and how they decide that- does anyone know this?

Delenn doesn't have much experience with a hostile press. I'm assuming the average Minbari has no interest in anything that's not their job and their family. It's rare for anything to be told to the common man at all. Declarations of war and peace, important events like Minbari joining the Alliance, etc.

I would assume that clan leaders play a role here, since they seem to be preeminent in the lives of their people.

The likely answer is 'those higher up the societal structure'. The Grey Council concealed the truth about the Battle of the Line for more than a decade.

@IanThompson (i realize you may know this) In-universe the truth about the Battle of the Line likely didn't go general public until it was leaked posthumously in Londo's pre-death recordings.  He traded Delenn and John and David Sheridan's freedom for the truth from Delenn when she was in  palace prison cell.  Per the novelization of In the beginning.  Prior to that only the highest level of Earthgov would have known (and the minbari told them at the surrender).  Ivanova was openly discussing B4 in the comic in Valen's name so there were probably rumors but no one put it all together.

This is extrapolation - I can't find anything explicit in the series or from JMS.
Firstly, the quote looks to me to apply at the level of each individual Minbari, not the general public as a group:

Back home, if there is something you need to know, you are told just what you require and no more. It is tradition.

Fundamentally, this is no different to what happens with humans - each individual who has information can make a decision on whether to share it with others or not. We generally tell people information that we think they will be interested in, or which we think they should know. Even our press doesn't share every bit of information (there's not the capacity to do so), so they filter and share the information of interest to their desired audience.
The amount of interest in things not directly related to themselves is different for the species though - as Delenn puts it,

You know, while this incessant curiosity may seem necessary to you Minbari respect the privacy of others by not prying into their affairs.

This suggests that the main driver to share information would be believing that it is important to the recipient, rather than necessarily of interest. As a group, this suits the Minbari.
Delenn is something of a special case (although quite possibly not the only one) - she is used to having access to more information as one of the Satai, and in her developing role with the Army of Light she believes she needs more information than others would consider relevant:

News dispenser: Unable to insert "Eye on Minbari" section. Do you wish to accept edition anyway?
Delenn: Yes. Yes, I do.
Sheridan: Eye on Minbari?
Delenn: It is good to know what your people are thinking and saying about my people.
Sheridan: Oh, sure.
Delenn: And I often learn things about my own world before I'm told what I need to know and no more.

So the decision making about disseminating information is much the same as on Earth (at least, pre-Clark) but culturally the amount of information shared is smaller and usually less likely to relate to personal revelations.
(All quotes from Divided Loyalties)
